# Euler beam, solving differential equation in python

Tags: python-3.x, differential-equations

I must solve the Euler Bernoulli differential beam equation which is:

```
w’’’’(x) = q(x)
```

and boundary conditions:

```
w(0) = w(l) = 0
```

and

```
w′′(0) = w′′(l) = 0
```

The beam is as shown on the picture below:

[beam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiBh1.png)

The continious force `q` is `2N/mm`.

I have to use shooting method and `scipy.integrate.odeint()` func.

I can't even manage to start as i do not understand how to write the differential equation as a system of equation

Can someone who understands solving of differential equations with boundary conditions in python please help!

Thanks :)

Comment: What does `w` stand for? I suppose `q` is the constant force?

Comment: I edited and corrected the mistake i wrote u''''(x) instead of w''''(x). And yes q(x) is the constant force.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transform the ODE into a first order system, setting `u0=w` one possible and usually used system is

```
    u0'=u1,
    u1'=u2,
    u2'=u3,
    u3'=q(x)
```

This can be implemented as

```
def ODEfunc(u,x): return [ u[1], u[2], u[3], q(x) ]
```

Then make a function that shoots with experimental initial conditions and returns the components of the second boundary condition

```
def shoot(u01, u03): return odeint(ODEfunc, [0, u01, 0, u03], [0, l])[-1,[0,2]]
```

Now you have a function of two variables with two components and you need to solve this 2x2 system with the usual methods. As the system is linear, the shooting function is linear as well and you only need to find the coefficients and solve the resulting linear system.

Comment: Thanks very much. I write the code and enter the values in the shoot function and i get a list with two components. What exactly is my sistem when there is only one set of numbers. Excuse me for my bad english.

Comment: To compute the components in `f(x)=Ax+b` you need to evaluate `f(0,0)`, `f(1,0)` and `f(0,1)`.

Answer (score 4):

### The shooting method

To solve the `fourth order ODE BVP` with `scipy.integrate.odeint()` using the `shooting method` you need to:

**1.)** Separate the `4th order ODE` into `4 first order ODEs` by substituting:

```
u = w
u1 = u' = w'           # 1
u2 = u1' = w''         # 2
u3 = u2' = w'''        # 3
u4 = u3' = w'''' = q   # 4
```

**2.)** Create a `function` to carry out the `derivation logic` and connect that function to the `integrate.odeint()` like this:

```
function calc(u, x , q)
{
    return [u[1], u[2], u[3] , q]
}

w = integrate.odeint(calc, [w(0), guess, w''(0), guess], xList, args=(q,))
```

**Explanation:**

We are sending the boundary value conditions to `odeint()` for `x=0` (`[w(0), w'(0) ,w''(0), w'''(0)]`) which calls the function `calc` which returns the derivatives to be added to the current state of `w`. Note that we are guessing the initial boundary conditions for `w'(0)` and `w'''(0)` while entering the known `w(0)=0` and `w''(0)=0`.

Addition of derivatives to the current state of `w` occurs like this:

```
# the current w(x) value is the previous value plus the current change of w in dx.
w(x) = w(x-dx) + dw/dx
# others are calculated the same
dw(x)/dx = dw(x-dx)/dx + d^2w(x)/dx^2
# etc.
```

This is why we are returning values `[u[1], u[2], u[3] , q]` instead of `[u[0], u[1], u[2] , u[3]]` from the `calc function`, because `u[1]` is the `first derivative` so we add it to `w`, etc.

**3.)** Now we are able to set up our `shooting method`. We will be sending `different initial boundary values` for `w'(0)` and `w'''(0)` to `odeint()` and then check the end result of the `returned w(x) profile` to determine how close `w(L)` and `w''(L)` got to `0` (the `known` boundary conditions).

### The program for the shooting method:

```
# a function to return the derivatives of w
def returnDerivatives(u, x, q):
    return [u[1], u[2], u[3], q]

# a shooting funtion which takes in two variables and returns a w(x) profile for x=[0,L]
def shoot(u2, u4):
    # the number of x points to calculate integration -> determines the size of dx
    # bigger number means more x's -> better precision -> longer execution time
    xSteps = 1001
    # length of the beam
    L= 1.0                 # 1m
    xSpace = np.linspace(0, L, xSteps)
    q = 0.02               # constant [N/m]
    # integrate and return the profile of w(x) and it's derivatives, from x=0 to x=L
    return odeint(returnDerivatives, [ 0, u2, 0, u4] , xSpace, args=(q,))

# the tolerance for our results.
tolerance = 0.01

# how many numbers to consider for u2 and u4 (the guess boundary conditions)
u2_u4_maxNumbers = 1327     # bigger number, better precision, slower program
# you can also divide into separate variables like u2_maxNum and u4_maxNum

# these are already tested numbers (the best results are somewhere in here)
u2Numbers = np.linspace(-0.1, 0.1, u2_u4_maxNumbers)
# the same as above
u4Numbers = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, u2_u4_maxNumbers)

# result list for extracted values of each w(x) profile => [u2Best, u4Best, w(L), w''(L)]
# which will help us determine if the w(x) profile is inside tolerance
resultList = []
# result list for each U (or w(x) profile) => [w(x), w'(x), w''(x), w'''(x)]
resultW = []

# start generating numbers for u2 and u4 and send them to odeint()
for u2 in u2Numbers:
    for u4 in u4Numbers:
        U = []
        U = shoot(u2,u4)
        # get only the last row of the profile to determine if it passes tolerance check
        result = U[len(U)-1]
        # only check w(L) == 0 and w''(L) == 0, as those are the known boundary cond.
        if (abs(result[0]) < tolerance) and (abs(result[2]) < tolerance):
            # if the result passed the tolerance check, extract some values from the
            # last row of the w(x) profile which we will need later for comaprisons
            resultList.append([u2, u4, result[0], result[2]])
            # add the w(x) profile to the list of profiles that passed the tolerance
            # Note: the order of resultList is the same as the order of resultW
            resultW.append(U)

# go through the resultList (list of extracted values from last row of each w(x) profile)
for i in range(len(resultList)):
    x = resultList[i]
    # both boundary conditions are 0 for both w(L) and w''(L) so we will simply add
    # the two absolute values to determine how much the sum differs from 0
    y = abs(x[2]) + abs(x[3])
    # if we've just started set the least difference to the current
    if i == 0:
        minNum = y    # remember the smallest difference to 0
        index = 0     # remember index of best profile
    elif y < minNum: 
        # current sum of absolute values is smaller
        minNum = y
        index = i

# print out the integral for w(x) over the beam
sum = 0
for i in resultW[index]:
    sum = sum + i[0]
print("The integral of w(x) over the beam is:")
print(sum/1001)    # sum/xSteps
```

This outputs:

```
The integral of w(x) over the beam is:
0.000135085272117
```

To print out the best profile for `w(x)` that we found:

```
print(resultW[index])
```

which outputs something like:

```
 #       w(x)             w'(x)           w''(x)           w'''(x)
[[  0.00000000e+00   7.54147813e-04   0.00000000e+00  -9.80392157e-03]
 [  7.54144825e-07   7.54142917e-04  -9.79392157e-06  -9.78392157e-03]
 [  1.50828005e-06   7.54128237e-04  -1.95678431e-05  -9.76392157e-03]
 ..., 
 [ -4.48774290e-05  -8.14851572e-04   1.75726275e-04   1.01560784e-02]
 [ -4.56921910e-05  -8.14670764e-04   1.85892353e-04   1.01760784e-02]
 [ -4.65067671e-05  -8.14479780e-04   1.96078431e-04   1.01960784e-02]]
```

---

**To double check the results from above we will also solve the `ODE` using the `numerical method`.**

---

### The numerical method

To solve the problem using the `numerical method` we first need to `solve the differential equations`. We will get `four constants` which we need to find with the help of the `boundary conditions`. The `boundary conditions` will be used to form a `system of equations` to help find the necessary `constants`.

For example:

```
w’’’’(x) = q(x);
```

means that we have this:

```
d^4(w(x))/dx^4 = q(x)
```

Since `q(x)` is constant after integrating we have:

```
d^3(w(x))/dx^3 = q(x)*x + C
```

After integrating again:

```
d^2(w(x))/dx^2 = q(x)*0.5*x^2 + C*x + D
```

After another integration:

```
dw(x)/dx = q(x)/6*x^3 + C*0.5*x^2 + D*x + E
```

And finally the last integration yields:

```
w(x) = q(x)/24*x^4 + C/6*x^3 + D*0.5*x^2 + E*x + F
```

Then we take a look at the `boundary conditions` (now we have expressions from above for `w''(x)` and `w(x)`) with which we make a `system of equations` to solve the `constants`.

```
w''(0) =>   0 = q(x)*0.5*0^2 + C*0 + D
w''(L) =>   0 = q(x)*0.5*L^2 + C*L + D
```

This gives us the `constants`:

```
D = 0            # from the first equation
C = - 0.01 * L   # from the second (after inserting D=0)
```

After repeating the same for `w(0)=0` and `w(L)=0` we obtain:

```
F = 0                  # from first
E = 0.01/12.0 * L^3    # from second
```

Now, after we have `solved the equation` and found all of the `integration constants` we can make the program for the `numerical method`.

### The program for the numerical method

We will make a `FOR` loop to go through the entire beam for every `dx` at a time and sum up (integrate) `w(x)`.

```
L = 1.0              # in meters
step = 1001.0        # how many steps to take (dx)
q = 0.02             # constant  [N/m]
integralOfW = 0.0;   # instead of w(0) enter the boundary condition value for w(0)

result = []

for i in range(int(L*step)):
    x= i/step
    w = (q/24.0*pow(x,4) - 0.02/12.0*pow(x,3) + 0.01/12*pow(L,3)*x)/step  # current w fragment
    # add up fragments of w for integral calculation
    integralOfW += w
    # add current value of w(x) to result list for plotting
    result.append(w*step);

print("The integral of w(x) over the beam is:")
print(integralOfW)
```

which outputs:

```
The integral of w(x) over the beam is:
0.00016666652805511192
```

---

**Now to compare the two methods**

---

### Result comparison between the shooting method and the numerical method

The integral of `w(x)` over the beam:

```
Shooting method  ->  0.000135085272117
Numerical method ->  0.00016666652805511192
```

That's a pretty good match, now lets see check the plots:

[image: Shooting method vs Numerical method - ODE]

From the plots it's even more obvious that we have a good match and that the results of the `shooting method` are correct.

To get even better results for the `shooting method` increase `xSteps` and `u2_u4_maxNumbers` to bigger numbers and you can also narrow down the `u2Numbers` and `u4Numbers` to the `same set size but a smaller interval` (around the best results from previous program runs). Keep in mind that setting `xSteps` and `u2_u4_maxNumbers` too high will cause your program to run for a very long time.

Comment: Thanks that was very useful. :)